# Emacs: How to specify the F3 key to Emacs 24's "scroll-down-line"?

Tags: macos, emacs

I found the functions `scroll-down-line` and `scroll-up-line` in Emacs 24 (Mac OS X 10.7.3). I can execute `M-x scroll-down-line` but I haven't managed to bind this to the F3 key.

I tried:

```
(global-set-key [f3] 'scroll-down-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f3>") 'scroll-down-line)
```

How can I correctly specify the F3 key so that the above functions work?

Note: I have set Mac OS X to accept the F-keys as proper F-keys, so I don't have to hit "fn-F3" to get "F3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yous specified it right as

```
(global-set-key [f3] 'scroll-down-line)
```

some thing else is happening.  What do you see when you run <kbd>C-h k
f3</kbd> after running the above line?

Comment: Nothing happens when I hit `C-h k f3`. I still see the "Describe key (or click or menu item)" dialog no matter how often I hit `f3`. That's strange.

Comment: Okay, I have it. I have an application installed which is called `Mousepose` and it uses the `f3` key. Since you only see the what `f3` does when `Mousepose` is active, I didn't see any change/influence. When I close this application, scrolling directly worked in Emacs. Thanks a lot.